# Javascript/Jquery: setTimeout function not running AJAX query via anonymous function

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a login page with some pretty animations.  I would like to be able to pause the script while I run a custom animation after the user submits the login post. To simplify:

Behavior: user submits login --> load custom animation --> wait 5 seconds --> execute AJAX post --> present error or navigate to home

Here is my code in its most working form

```
    function ValidateUser() {
        var userid = $("#Username").attr('value');
        var pass = $("#Password").attr('value');
        var url = "/Account/ValidateUser";
        var $this = $('.login'),
          $state = $this.find('button > .state');
        $this.addClass('loading');
        $state.html('Authenticating');
        setTimeout(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: { username: userid, password: pass },
                cache: false,
                type: "POST",
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data == "1") {
                        $this.addClass('ok');
                        $state.html('Welcome back!');
                        window.location.href = "Home/Index";
                    } else {
                        $state.html('Incorrect username or password!');
                        $this.addClass('loginError');
                        $this.removeClass('ok loading');
                    }
                    $("#txtuserid").attr({ 'value': '' });
                    $("#txtpassword").attr({ 'value': '' });
                },
                error: function (reponse) {
                    alert(response);
                    $state.html('An unknown error has occurred!');
                    $this.addClass('loginError');
                    $this.removeClass('ok loading');
                }
            });
        }, 5000);
    }
```

After running it through firefox's javascript debugger I noticed that the ajax post is never actually run.  I am developing in visual studio using C# and I place a breakpoint on the validate user method but it never hits the breakpoint.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
Here is the HTML I use to call the ValidateUser method.

```
    <button onclick="ValidateUser()">
            <i class="spinner"></i>
            <span id="submit" class="state">Submit</span>
    </button>
```

Comment: how is ValidateUser called?

Comment: ValidateUser is called onClick from button in login form.

Comment: @adeneo I agree. However, this is for demonstration purposes. So I am aiming to impress.

Comment: Put a debug point with chrome dev tools on that setttimeout. I think your url variable may not be defined when you try to reference it from the anon function. Or just hard-code the url there for testing purposes.

Comment: @Nikki9696 Does the timeout function run before everything else? because if you follow it programmatically, the url variable is defined before the setTimeout method. However, I'll go ahead and define the url in the ajax post.

Comment: @mplungjan how would you recommend that use console.log?  Should I print out variables at the start of and finish of the timeout function? What do you recommend?

Comment: @Nate-Dawg: javascript variables are weird and their scope is determined by their closure. that's why i figure it's easier to plug it in and see if that fixes it, that would mean it's a scope issue

Comment: @Nikki9696 I checked it out and it still ends up skipping the AJAX post, even with the url inserted as a string.

Comment: @Nate-Dawg ok cool, so now, how do you know it's skipping it? c# debug, or FF/Chrome debug? Just for giggles, stick an alert in there just before the ajax, in the setttimeout anon function. Let's make sure it isn't an issue with the debugger

Comment: Well, I set a breakpoint in visual studio on the method it tried to contact. It never hits that breakpoint. This my assumption that the ajax is never actually posted.

Comment: @Nate-Dawg VS sucks at that for browsers other than IE. Use FF debugger, or use IE and VS breakpoints. You can also run in debug mode and set a breakpoint on your /Account/ValidateUser controller to see if it's being called (if that's what you meant already, sorry)  Also, I assume you've already looked at the FF console to be sure no errors were generated

Comment: I think you misunderstand. Or I'm just not explaining well enough lol. I have two breakpoints set. One in FF debugger on the ValidateUser method and one in Visual studio on the account controller.

Comment: It never reaches the breakpoint on the account controller method.

Comment: I'm out of ideas  :)  I tested this simplistically over on jsfiddle and the settimeout seems fine and requested a page for me after time elapsed, so it must be something else about it.

Comment: Really? So the issue isn't syntax or structure? That's a relief. Helps me narrow down the issue. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm running the project locally via an instance with iis, would that cause an issue?

Comment: Could you send me the code you put in jsfiddle? This is my first time using setTimeout, so maybe it will give me some insight what i need to change.

Comment: I meant `setTimeout(function () { console.log("in sto");
            $.ajax({
...                success: function (data) { console.log("success",data)`

Comment: @implunjan good idea. I'll check that.

Comment: And if the button is submitting the form you will also have a problem. PLEASE post relevant code including how you call the function. You likely want `$("#formID").on("submit",function (e) { e.preventDefault(); 
        var userid = $("#Username").attr('value');....`

Comment: @mplungjan I hadn't thought about that!!  Let me give that a try and get back to you.

Comment: @mplungjan  THAT WAS IT!! You freaking rock.  Thanks everyone for your help.  mplungjan if you would like to submit an answer outlining the solution I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the button is submitting the form you will have a problem.

A button without `type="button"` will submit - in some browsers actually submit to the page URL if no form

You likely want

```
$("#formID").on("submit",function (e) { 
  e.preventDefault(); 
  var userid = $("#Username").attr('value');....
```

Comment: Thank you sir! You are a life saver. I hate simple answers though..  It's always the little things.

Comment: Add 'type="button"` is an alternative